# How to use created variable in same assign function with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Some simple data to get us started:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.normal(size=100), "y": np.random.normal(size=100)})
```

So, up until this point, I always thought that `assign` was the equivalent of `mutate` in the `dplyr` library. However, if I try to use a variable that I have created in an `assign` step in that same `assign` step, I get an error. Consider the following, which is acceptable in R:

```
df %>%
  mutate(z = x * y, w = z + 10)
```

If I try the equivalent in `pandas`, I get an error:

```
df.assign(z = df.x * df.y, w = z + 10) # Error
df.assign(z = df.x * df.y, w = lambda d: d.z + 10) # Error
```

The only way I can think of to do this is to use two `assign` steps:

```
df.assign(z = df.x * df.y).assign(w = lambda d: d.z + 10)
```

Is there something that I've missed? Or is there another function that is more appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.eval(..., inplace=False)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method as follows:

```
In [79]: qry = """
    ...: z = x * y
    ...: w = z + 10    # NOTE: next variable must be on a new line 
    ...: """

In [80]: df.eval(qry, inplace=False)
Out[80]:
           x         y         z          w
0  -0.636271 -0.493260  0.313847  10.313847
1   0.298998  0.266673  0.079735  10.079735
2  -0.836940 -0.593346  0.496595  10.496595
3   0.497099 -0.199589 -0.099215   9.900785
4   2.187165 -0.332140 -0.726445   9.273555
5   0.472785  0.169204  0.079997  10.079997
6  -0.847666 -1.519570  1.288088  11.288088
7   1.262524  1.008820  1.273660  11.273660
8  -0.632817 -0.463941  0.293590  10.293590
9  -0.955913 -1.149799  1.099107  11.099107
10 -1.260231  0.000266 -0.000336   9.999664
11  1.054885 -1.390762 -1.467094   8.532906
12 -1.048271  0.816762 -0.856187   9.143813
13 -0.814064 -0.070574  0.057452  10.057452
14 -1.279904 -1.079151  1.381211  11.381211
15  0.223787 -0.887732 -0.198663   9.801337
16 -0.493267 -0.064099  0.031618  10.031618
17 -0.549534  0.622976 -0.342346   9.657654
18 -0.261209  0.267250 -0.069808   9.930192
19 -2.948658  1.586422 -4.677815   5.322185
20 -1.959709  1.103462 -2.162465   7.837535
21  0.595782 -0.699891 -0.416983   9.583017
22 -0.059947 -0.264011  0.015827  10.015827
23  0.012929 -1.635020 -0.021139   9.978861
24  1.387415 -1.763467 -2.446660   7.553340
..       ...       ...       ...        ...
75  1.649346 -0.515930 -0.850948   9.149052
76 -1.111928 -0.674379  0.749861  10.749861
77  1.413567 -1.377679 -1.947441   8.052559
78  0.119227  0.382638  0.045621  10.045621
79  0.064824 -2.043595 -0.132474   9.867526
80 -1.135878 -0.116922  0.132809  10.132809
81 -0.423820  1.386475 -0.587616   9.412384
82  0.642123 -0.914807 -0.587419   9.412581
83 -0.495118  0.773073 -0.382763   9.617237
84  0.347832 -0.913034 -0.317582   9.682418
85  1.314090  1.633140  2.146093  12.146093
86 -0.277789  0.883307 -0.245373   9.754627
87  0.514091 -1.349400 -0.693714   9.306286
88 -0.140958 -0.264500  0.037283  10.037283
89 -0.975843 -0.608312  0.593617  10.593617
90  0.242816  0.749860  0.182078  10.182078
91  1.185033 -0.487483 -0.577683   9.422317
92 -0.258952 -0.532178  0.137809  10.137809
93  2.015797  1.788613  3.605481  13.605481
94 -0.415403  0.224944 -0.093442   9.906558
95 -0.082239 -1.479761  0.121693  10.121693
96 -0.707825  2.074192 -1.468165   8.531835
97  0.517926  0.043832  0.022702  10.022702
98 -0.667368 -0.916520  0.611656  10.611656
99  0.366614  0.620221  0.227382  10.227382

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Ah this is actually a nice alternative, +1

Comment: I didn't know you could perform multi-line evals like that, very interesting.

Comment: This is certainly an approach that achieves what I want. I'd still love to use the `assign` function instead, since I think the function name is more intuitive, but this definitely solves my issue in the interim.

Answer (score 2):

These are not equivalent. From the docs for [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) (*emphasis mine*):

> Assigning multiple columns within the same assign is possible, but you **cannot reference other columns created within the same assign call**.

This would be tricky to do in Python < 3.6 since the order of keyword arguments is not guaranteed. [maxU's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496633/4686625) answer using a multi-line `DataFrame.eval` is a nice alternative approach to the problem.

---

There is also a GitHub issue

- **[API: allow dependent assignment? #14207](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14207)**

which notes that this behavior you want *could* be possible in Python 3.6 since [kwarg argument order is preserved](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-468-preserving-keyword-argument-order). It appears that the behavior may be adopted in pandas 2.0.

Comment: Well... that's unfortunate. I'm also not sure how I missed that blatantly obvious answer in the docs, but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @brittenb Found a bit more info if you're interested, see my edit.

Comment: That would be a very nice addition indeed. Would certainly help to clean up a lot of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I believe that pandas now allows for this type of operation:

```
df.assign(z = df.x * df.y, w = lambda d: d.z + 10)
```

At least having read this part of the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

So I guess it depends on the pandas version!